# Compare values in the same column and add the result in a second column in R

Tags: r

I am comparing values in the same column for different rows and depending on the value I want to give a result.
Below the table. I have the IDs and I want to get the values of the column "Result". The column "What I have" is what I get from my function.
Conditions for the results:
If the ID (n) is different from the ID of the row before (n-1), then Result (n) is A.
If the ID (n) is the same as in the ID of the row before and different from the next row (n+1), then Result (n) is C.
Other cases is B.

```
l <- ifelse ((df$ID[1:(nrow(df)-1)] != df$ID[2:(nrow(df)+0)]),print("A"),
ifelse(((df$ID[1:(nrow(df)-1)] == df$ID[2:(nrow(df)+0)]) & (df$ID[2:(nrow(df)+0)] != df$ID[3:(nrow(df)+1)])), print ("C"),print ("B")))

    df
    ID Result What I have
1   12   A       A
2   13   A       A
3   14   A       A
4   15   A       B
5   15   B       B
6   15   B       B
7   15   B       B
8   15   B       C
9   15   C       A
10  16   A      NA
11  17   A      NA
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lead` from `dplyr` and `ifelse` you could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
df$Result <- ifelse(df$ID != lag(df$ID) | is.na(lag(df$ID)), 'A',
                    ifelse(df$ID == lag(df$ID) & df$ID != lead(df$ID), 'C', 'B' ))
```

Output:

```
> df
   ID Result
1  12      A
2  13      A
3  14      A
4  15      A
5  15      B
6  15      B
7  15      B
8  15      B
9  15      C
10 16      A
11 17      A
```

A few words for clarification: `lag` shifts the column by 1 row whereas `lead` does exactly the opposite thing i.e. takes the column back by 1 row. Check `lag(df$ID)` and `lead(df$ID)` for visualizing it.

Comment: You are welcome @JaviLarry, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `rleid` from `data.table`.  We group by the run-length type id of 'ID' variable.  Use a logical condition to create the 'Result' variable, i.e. `if` the number of elements is greater than 1 (`.N >1`), we concatenate 'A' with replicate of 'B' and 'C' or `else` to return 'A'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, Result:=if(.N>1) c('A', rep('B', .N-2), 'C') else 'A' ,
                   by = rleid(ID)]
df 
#    ID Result
# 1: 12      A
# 2: 13      A
# 3: 14      A
# 4: 15      A
# 5: 15      B
# 6: 15      B
# 7: 15      B
# 8: 15      B
# 9: 15      C
#10: 16      A
#11: 17      A
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID= c(12:14, rep(15, 6), 16:17))
```